# grab Key values from PieChart selections

Tags: dc.js

I would like to grab the key value/s from selected PieChart slices so I can use them elsewhere on my page. Just as a basic text list of the selections made from the PieChart, I don't need the corresponding value.

I think that I need to use a Listener on the PieChart and keyAccessor but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Can anyone help or point me at an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the 'filtered' event:

```
    chart.on('filtered.my_event', function (chart) {
        // chart.filters() contains the current selection
        console.log(chart.filters());
    });
```

`.filters()` returns an array of keys, should not need to processed further.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I am sorry but I'm still not sure how to then pass that array to, for example the console.

Comment: Hi Gordon. Thanks for the update. I have tried the above with a PieChart but I'm getting nothing showing up in my console? Is there anything else I should be doing? I will try and get a fiddle together to see if that shows it.

Comment: Works for me modifying `web/examples/pie.html`. Example output: `["run-19", "run-20"]`

Comment: to be clear, i get these events when clicking on pie chart slices. to monitor the effects of other charts filtering would be something different.

Comment: Hi Gordon, using the example and stripping everything else out of my page  it works as expected. Must be something else in there causing a hiccup. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It looks like it's Dynatable causing the issue, removing it and everything is as it should be. The following is within the dynatable 
        `for (var i = 0; i < dc.chartRegistry.list().length; i++) {
               var chartI = dc.chartRegistry.list()[i];
               chartI.on("filtered", RefreshTable);
           }
           RefreshTable();`

Comment: ah, i had no idea that dynatable hooked into dc.js like that, looks pretty wrong. anyway, you can avoid that by namespacing, adding a `.name` suffix - i've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I was just messing around with dynatable and I'm not sure I will be using it but this is good to know.